# Bubble should close if we click any where on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#username_input').live("focus", function() {
             $('.user-available-info').hide();
             $('.user-available-error').hide();
             $('.login-error').hide();
     });
    $('#password_input').live("focus", function() {
             $('.login-error').hide();
             $( '#login-username-invalid').hide();
             $( '#login-username-error').hide();
         });
    This is the xhtml page
    <h:panelGroup id="login-username-invalid" >
    <div id="login-username-invalid-error">     
                <div class="login-error">
                    <div class="login-error-top"></div>
                    <div class="login-error-middle">

    <p class="error">
    "message to be displayed in the bubble"</P>
```

We got a login page in our application,where a error bubble pops up if the user enters a invalid username or password. We got a requirement where the bubble should close if the user clicks any where on the page.It works fine for both the username and password input fields as,i have given the .hide as listed in the code above.But i tried changing the input field ids to 'body' in order to make it work on whole the page.But it never worked.I tried the .click and .bind neither of them worked.Is there any solution
        for it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

bind to the click on body, not the focus: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/QDjSV/1/

```
$('body').on('focus', function(){
    alert('body does not recieve focus');
});
$('body').on('click', function(){
    alert('body does recieve click');
});
```

Comment: so $('body').on('click', function(){
$('.bubbleclass').hide();}); will make this work right.and will hide the the bubble if clicked any where on the page right.

Comment: Yes.  Two things to watch out for.  html and body should have a css height and width of 100%.  Also, make sure to handle the case where a user clicks on the bubble itself.  You probably don't want it to close then: $('.bubbleclass').on('click', function(){return false;}); Otherwise the click will 'bubble' up to the body and close 'your' bubble.